# Removing some lines according to a little complicated condition

Tags: bash

Text file’s content is as follows.

```
600466 a 37.50 25.28
600466 b 31.13 18.22
600466 c 64.80 61.39
600467 a 38.79 30.00
600467 b 28.73 41.04
600467 c 58.32 61.39
600468 a 33.09 25.28
600468 b 35.57 42.69
600468 c 58.32 60.12
600469 a 36.89 29.80
600469 b 35.57 30.94
600469 c 64.80 62.49
600470 b 37.35 35.02 *
600470 c 58.32 58.32 *
600471 a 29.22 25.47
600471 b 34.74 20.61
600471 c 64.80 62.81
600472 b 31.13 30.28*
600472 c 58.32 62.04 *
```

I checked some lines with an asterisk.

You can get the first field of a line repeats 3 times(so it appears exactly 3 times consecutively), but some lines are not. I want remove that lines with a few shell commands.

Does anyone have a fancy idea?

(any correction of my poor English would be welcomed. Thank you for advance)

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the asterisk lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cut -d' ' -f1 file \
| uniq -c \
| grep -v ' 3 ' \
| rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev \
| grep -vwFf- file > output
```

The first line outputs the first column.

The second line counts how often each value was present.

The third line excludes those lines that were present 3 times.

The fourth line removes the counts.

The fifth line excludes the strings from the original file.

Comment: In OSX, `grep -f -` does not work. But I found an answer from your advise. Thank you! `grep -vwf <(cat data.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 != 3' | cut -d' ' -f5 | sort -n | sed 's/^/^/' ) data.txt > rslt.txt`

Comment: @plhn well you did ask for a "fancy idea"... :-). Seriously though, this is not how you would really do this job in shell. This uses multiple tools and pipes when 1 tool would do the job and would take a massive amount of time to complete as your file size grows. You are WAY off the mark. The guys who invented shell to manipulate files and processes and sequence calls to tools also invented the tool `awk` for shell to call to manipulate text - just use it.

Comment: You're welcome. Sounds like you're just starting to learn shell so you'll either learn awk now (get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins) or dismiss it and continue learning to use more and more convoluted shell scripts until 10 years from now you look back and wonder what the heck you've been doing...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '++c[$1]<=3{m[$1]=m[$1]?m[$1]"\n"$0:$0}c[$1]==3{print m[$1]}c[$1]>3'
```

Explained better in multiline, not optimized version:

*example.awk:*

```
{
    # Count the occurences of $1
    c[$1]++
}

c[$1]<=3{
    # Append the current line to a temporary storage. If the
    # temporary storage doesn't exist, create it.
    m[$1]=m[$1]?m[$1]"\n"$0:$0
}

# Print the temporary storage once $1 has appeared 3 times 
c[$1]==3{
    printf "%s\n", m[$1]
}

# Print the current line if the count of $1 is above '3'
c[$1]>3
```

Call it like this:

```
awk -f example.awk input.txt
```

Output:

```
600466 a 37.50 25.28
600466 b 31.13 18.22
600466 c 64.80 61.39
600467 a 38.79 30.00
600467 b 28.73 41.04
600467 c 58.32 61.39
600468 a 33.09 25.28
600468 b 35.57 42.69
600468 c 58.32 60.12
600469 a 36.89 29.80
600469 b 35.57 30.94
600469 c 64.80 62.49
600471 a 29.22 25.47
600471 b 34.74 20.61
600471 c 64.80 62.81
```

Answer (score 2):

if you can never have more than 3 consecutive rows with matching keys then:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 != prev { buf=""; cnt=0 }
{ buf = buf $0 ORS; cnt++; prev=$1 }
cnt == 3 { printf "%s", buf }
```

otherwise:

```
$ cat tst.awk
($1 != prev) && (NR>1) {
    if (cnt == 3) {
        printf "%s", buf
    }
    buf = ""
    cnt = 0
}
{ buf = buf $0 ORS; cnt++; prev=$1 }
END {
    if (cnt == 3) {
        printf "%s", buf
    }
}
```

Either way:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
600466 a 37.50 25.28
600466 b 31.13 18.22
600466 c 64.80 61.39
600467 a 38.79 30.00
600467 b 28.73 41.04
600467 c 58.32 61.39
600468 a 33.09 25.28
600468 b 35.57 42.69
600468 c 58.32 60.12
600469 a 36.89 29.80
600469 b 35.57 30.94
600469 c 64.80 62.49
600471 a 29.22 25.47
600471 b 34.74 20.61
600471 c 64.80 62.81
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

```
awk '$1 != prev_1 {if (a[prev_1]==3) print buffer; buffer=""}
    {a[$1]++; buffer = (buffer?buffer ORS:"") $0}
    {prev_1=$1}
    END {if (a[$1]==3) print buffer}' file
```

That is, store the buffer in the variable `buffer` and print it whenever the first field changes, just in case the counter of it is exactly `3`.

#### Test

```
$  awk '$1 != prev_1 {if (a[prev_1]==3) print buffer; buffer=""} {a[$1]++; buffer = (buffer?buffer ORS:"") $0} {prev_1=$1} END {if (a[$1]==3) print buffer}' a
600466 a 37.50 25.28
600466 b 31.13 18.22
600466 c 64.80 61.39
600467 a 38.79 30.00
600467 b 28.73 41.04
600467 c 58.32 61.39
600468 a 33.09 25.28
600468 b 35.57 42.69
600468 c 58.32 60.12
600469 a 36.89 29.80
600469 b 35.57 30.94
600469 c 64.80 62.49
600471 a 29.22 25.47
600471 b 34.74 20.61
600471 c 64.80 62.81
```