# Delete a variable in awk

Tags: variables, awk

I wonder if it is possible to delete a variable in `awk`. For an array, you can say `delete a[2]` and the index `2` of the array `a[]` will be deleted. However, for a variable I cannot find a way.

The closest I get is to say `var=""` or `var=0`.

But then, it seems that the default value of a non-existing variable is `0` or `False`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {if (b==0) print 5}'
5
$ awk 'BEGIN {if (!b) print 5}' 
5
```

So I also wonder if it is possible to distinguish between a variable that is set to `0` and a variable that has not been set, because it seems not to:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {a=0; if (a==b) print 5}'
5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no operation to unset/delete a variable. The only time a variable becomes unset again is at the end of a function call when it's an unused function argument being used as a local variable:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function foo( arg ) {
    if ( (arg=="") && (arg==0) ) {
        print "arg is not set"
    }
    else {
        printf "before assignment: arg=<%s>\n",arg
    }
    arg = rand()
    printf "after assignment: arg=<%s>\n",arg
    print "----"
}
BEGIN {
    foo()
    foo()
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
arg is not set
after assignment: arg=<0.237788>
----
arg is not set
after assignment: arg=<0.291066>
----
```

so if you want to perform some actions A then unset the variable X and then perform actions B, you could encapsulate A and/or B in functions using X as a local var.

Note though that the default value is zero or null, not zero or false, since its type is "numeric string".

You test for an unset variable by comparing it to both null and zero:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ if ((x=="") && (x==0)) print "y" }'
y
$ awk 'BEGIN{ x=0; if ((x=="") && (x==0)) print "y" }'
$ awk 'BEGIN{ x=""; if ((x=="") && (x==0)) print "y" }'
```

If you NEED to have a variable you delete then you can always use a single-element array:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ if ((x[1]=="") && (x[1]==0)) print "y" }'
y
$ awk 'BEGIN{ x[1]=""; if ((x[1]=="") && (x[1]==0)) print "y" }'
$ awk 'BEGIN{ x[1]=""; delete x; if ((x[1]=="") && (x[1]==0)) print "y" }'
y
```

but IMHO that obfuscates your code.

What would be the use case for unsetting a variable? What would you do with it that you can't do with `var=""` or `var=0`?

Comment: Everything started in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33942659/1983854) when trying to blank the `stack` variable. To me, it looked a bit weird having to kind-of-hardcode `var=""` instead of plainly removing it.

Comment: Yeah I get it, if the stack was implemented as an array you'd delete the array but it's implemented as a string so why can't you delete it? The answer is just that that's not how you init a string in any language. Of course you could always implement it as a string stored entirely in `stack[1]` and then cheerfully delete `stack` but that wouldn't improve your code's readability!

Comment: @EdMorton `awk 'BEGIN {a=0; if (a==b && length(b)>0) print 5}'` can it work?

Comment: @EdMorton  if the variable `b` is unset .... I mean .... `awk 'BEGIN {a=0; if (a==b && length(a)==length(b)) print 5}'` in other words

Comment: Still not sure what the question is but here's what happens: `length()` is a string function so `length(b)` will treat `b` as a string and will return `0` whether `b` had never been set or had explicitly be set to `""`. If you set `a` to zero then `length(a)` (i.e. the length of the contents of `a` converted to a string) is `1`. So although when `b` is unset and `a=0`, `a==b` will be true (since `b` has the value `zero or null` which will be treated as `zero` in this numeric comparison context), `length(a)==length(b)` will be false (since `b` will be treated as `null` in this string context).

Comment: Beautiful! So a big remark to `You test for an unset variable by comparing it to both null and zero`.

Comment: Counter example: `$ awk 'BEGIN{ arg=a; if ((arg=="") && (arg==0)) print "arg is not set"; }'` prints `arg is not set`.

Comment: What value do you think `arg` was set to? a=7 and arg=a => arg=7. a is unset and arg=a => arg is unset. I guess maybe it depends what you think "set" means in this context but to me it means "populated with a specific value".

Answer (score 2):

An unset variable expands to `""` or `0`, depending on the context in which it is being evaluated.

For this reason, I would say that it's a matter of preference and depends on the usage of the variable.

Given that we use `a + 0` (or the slightly controversial `+a`) in the `END` block to coerce the potentially unset variable `a` to a numeric type, I guess you could argue that the natural "empty" value would be `""`.

I'm not sure that there's too much to read in to the cases that you've shown in the question, given the following:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { if (!"") print  }'
5
```

(`""` is false, unsurprisingly)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { if (b == "") print 5 }'
5
```

(unset variable evaluates equal to `""`, just the same as `0`)

Comment: wrt that last point, no it is removing the index as well as what it pointed to in memory - try `2 in a` after `delete a[2]`.

Comment: @Ed I guess that interpreting the output of `2 in a` correctly would require knowledge of exactly what the test is doing (I don't know!)

Comment: `a` is a hash table, `2 in a` is accessing the memory location you get to when you hash `2`. If it's populated then `2 in a` succeeds, otherwise it doesn't. When you say `delete a[2]` you are freeing the memory at the location that hashing `2` points to.

Comment: I accepted Ed Morton's answer because it gives the key comment: "You test for an unset variable by comparing it to both null and zero". Nevertheless, this was also very useful and you showed me the trick of `+a` which I did not know. Many thanks!