# Testing a non existent variable in awk

Tags: awk

I want to test the value of a variable that may or not exist, and I'm doing:

```
if(a<1) print "fail"
```

That works fine.

If I then re-test the same variable and if this one was not set in the first place, `awk` will see this variable as set.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{if(a<1) print "fail"; if(a) print "fail"; }'
fail
```

In the above statement, I would expect that nothing is printing because the variable `a` is never set to anything.

Do you have any explanation why such a behavior?

If that matters, I'm using `GNU Awk 4.2.1`

Comment: You are seeing the first "fail". Better check with different strings: `awk 'BEGIN{if(a<1) print "fail1"; if(a) print "fail2"; }'`. Apart from that, it is a bit unclear what the question is here

Comment: [You test for an unset variable by comparing it to both null and zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33943113/1983854)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Background: All scalar awk variables are eventually of type "numeric" or "string". An uninitialized variable is of a different type known as "numeric string" since it's unknown what it's eventual type will be and it has the unique value of zero-or-null. User input that looks like a number is also of type numeric string but obviously has a specific value, not zero-or-null. The first time a variable is used awk determines it's final type (numeric or string) by the context in which that variable is used.

So in your code you have:

```
if(a<1) print "fail"
```

`a` hasn't been set so it has the value zero-or-null and in a context like comparing to the number 1, no matter whether you consider it zero or null, both possible values are less than 1 and so `"fail"` is printed. There's a chart at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variable-Typing that shows you that numeric comparison is actually being used but it doesn't matter in this case.

So, your code is not setting `a` after the first time it is tested as you thought it was. A more interesting test that better demonstrates whats happening would be:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{if(a<1) print "is lt 1"; if(a=="") print "is null"; if (a==0) print "is 0" }'
is lt 1
is null
is 0

$ awk 'BEGIN{a=0; if(a<1) print "is lt 1"; if(a=="") print "is null"; if (a==0) print "is 0" }'
is lt 1
is 0

$ awk 'BEGIN{a=""; if(a<1) print "is lt 1"; if(a=="") print "is null"; if (a==0) print "is 0" }'
is lt 1
is null
```

Answer (score 2):

unassigned variables take "false" value, that is 0 or empty string based on the context they are referred to.  This may clarify...

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{if(a==0)  print "a=0"; 
             if(a=="") print "a=\"\""; 
             if(!a)    print "a is false"}'
```

prints

```
a=0
a=""
a is false
```

Answer (score 0):

From the doc

> AWK variables are dynamic; they come into existence when they are first used.
>   ...
>   Uninitialized variables have the numeric value 0 and the string value "" (the null, or empty, string).

In your statement:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{if(a<1) print "fail"; if(a) print "fail"; }'
```

Since `a` is initialized with `0` (or `""`), `if (a<1)` succeeds and `if (a)` fails.